# How to access the cataloged libs of an android project within a kotlin extension for gradle files?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have the following problem in my gradle files:
Some parts of the code repeat the implementation of some libs a lot, for this, I will take Jetpack Compose as an example.
In several gradle modules I have the following code repetition:

In my `build.gradle.kts` of the feature:

```
dependencies {
    // Other dependencies...

    // Compose
    implementation(platform(libs.composeBom))
    implementation(libs.ui)
    implementation(libs.uiGraphics)
    implementation(libs.uiToolingPreview)
    implementation(libs.viewModelKtx)
    implementation(libs.lifecycleRuntimeCompose)
    implementation(libs.hiltNavigationCompose)
    implementation(libs.material3)
    debugImplementation(libs.uiTooling)
    debugImplementation(libs.uiTestManifest)
}
```

My idea is having the next in the future:

```
dependencies {
    // Other dependencies...
    compose()
}
```

So, for this, I created a `buildSrc` at the root of my project to write the `compose()` extension that'll do it for me:

[image]

And at my `DependencyHandlesScopeEx` I have the following extension:

```kotlin
fun DependencyHandler.compose() {
    add("implementation", platform(libs.composeBom))
    add("implementation", libs.ui)
    add("implementation", libs.uiGraphics)
    add("implementation", libs.uiToolingPreview)
    add("implementation", libs.viewModelKtx)
    add("implementation", libs.lifecycleRuntimeCompose)
    add("implementation", libs.hiltNavigationCompose)
    add("implementation", libs.material3)
    add("debugImplementation", libs.uiTooling)
    add("debugImplementation", libs.uiTestManifest)
}
```

But it's not working as expected because I'm having the following syntax error:
***Unresolved reference: libs***

I'm using version catalogs and this property `libs` is normally accessed from a gradle file, but not from my `DependencyHandler.compose()` extension. How can I solve that?